# Randomly Images are uploaded of 0 bytes PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently setup load balancing for my website wordpress blog 2 back-end nodes with HAproxy. Now i am facing a very strange issue. Images are uploading of 0 Bytes randomly.Some images are uploading fine and some are not.This issue happens when I upload post through window live writer.

When I retry 0 Bytes Images they uploaded successfully.

PHP Configuration

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 8M
max_file_uploads = 40
post_max_size = 8M
max_input_time = 60
```

Images uploaded through WP or Window Live writer uploaded to server then using lsyncd images sent to the image server.

I am not able to figure out the issue. Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would check following:

- image uploaded on one server but being use on another (make sure your file processed within one request)
- upload data time limit is too short

PS: could you be more specific in your question, describe software you are using, add you config. It will help to localize the issue.

Comment: This should be a comment. It's not an actual solution to the problem, since you can't really know what the problem and conditions are.

Comment: @AlejandroIván well, if the problem turns out to be that time limit was too short or image is being used on another server, this is an actual solution to the problem. (Or, to be exact, definition of the cause of the problem. Solution seems to left to the reader.)

Comment: @eis true, just saying that answering is too premature right now :)